# Standalone GNOME menu

Tags: gnome

Is there a "standalone" version of the GNOME applications menu? That is, a **simple** widget that can be positioned anywhere on the desktop (and closed!), like a normal window, that will expand when clicked to show all my applications.

(Then I can launch it via ssh+X from my laptop, and run apps on my desktop computer without needing to fire up a terminal and type `ssh -X -C desktop.local some_x_app` every time.)

Comment: Another option: take a look at https://launchpad.net/cardapio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about GnoMenu? As stated it is:

> GnoMenu is an eye-candy GNOME menu with themes support which works with the GNOME Panel, Avant Window Navigator, Cairo Dock, KDE Plasma and starting with the latest 2.9 version: Docky.

Ubuntu version:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnomenu-team/ppa

$ sudo apt-get update sudo apt-get install gnomenu
```

Or get it from https://launchpad.net/gnomenu

Comment: Nice! This is exactly what I was after. Bounty will follow in... 20 hours.

Answer (score 1):

You may like [Gnome-Do](http://do.davebsd.com/) or the [Circular Menu](http://code.google.com/p/circular-application-menu/).

Comment: I use Do, but I can't run it over ssh+X because I already run it on my laptop normally. Although... maybe I could remove the keybinding and force it to the tray...

Comment: ...no, wait, I can't because then I can't use it properly on my desktop.

Answer (score 0):

What about positioning your menu at the top and the X11 forwarded one at the bottom with auto-hide?

---

**Edit 1:**
From [a mailinglist](http://www.mail-archive.com/debian-gtk-gnome@lists.debian.org/msg13379.html):

> From gconftool --help-all:
>
> Load/Save options:
>
> --dump      Dump to standard output an XML description of all entries
>   under a directory, recursively.
>     --load      Load from the specified file an XML description of values
>   and set them relative to a directory.
>
> So "gconftool --dump /apps/panel > my-panel-settings.xml" and later
>   "gconfool --load < my-panel-settings.xml" should make it.
>
> Or look into [Sabayon](http://live.gnome.org/Sabayon/), maybe.

Try one of these tools, it should allow you to use the panel over X11 with a different configuration than the current configuration on the remote computer itself, good luck! :-)

**Edit 2:** What about just creating shortcuts that execute the ssh command line?

Comment: Like with Gnome Do, there would be a mismatch between the configuration for my desktop and for the laptop. Is there any way to tell a particular launch of the panel to use a certain configuration?

Comment: Do my edits help? The first edit is what you ask. The second edit is the way I plan to do it... I'm running Windows 7 x64 and run a headless Gentoo VM with X11, I use Putty as a terminal and Xming to show the applications on my Windows. I really love this as it gives me the best of both worlds... The only problem I still have is starting applications and I'm planning to create shortcuts that initiate them over a SSH connection, I might as well create one hidden Putty window to keep the X11 open. X11 won't survive sleep mode either, but when that fact annoys me I can use Xvnc to work around it.